# this.globalvar vs window.globalvar

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I recently read somewhere (I am really sorry I can't provide the source) that you can use `this.varname` to access globals in replacement to `window.varname` to save 2 chars

```
var myVar = "global";
function myFunc() {
    var myVar = "notGlobal";
    alert( this.myVar ); //global
}
```

It seems to work, but I want to know if:

- it is safe to use in old browsers
- it is cross-browser compatible
- it will fail under some weird circumstances

Comment: You can only do that when your code is running in the global scope (the scope of `window`). Don't do it to "save 2 chars".

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: No, by default a function call's `this` also refers to the global object.

Comment: It should be safe anywhere that `this` refers to the `window` object. Elsewhere, however, I don't think there's any guarantee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I'd do it, but it's completely cross-browser compatible ***if*** `this` is referring to the global object (`window`). Whether it is will depend on how the function in question was called (at global scope, `this` does indeed refer to the global object), and whether the code in question is in "strict mode" or not. (In [strict mode](http://es5.github.com/#x10.1.1), `this` does **not** refer to the global object. [Kudos and upvotes to Esailija for pointing that out.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383177/157247))

In non-strict code:

So at global scope:

```
console.log(this === window); // true if not in strict mode
```

And similarly, if you have a function you call directly:

```
function foo() {
   console.log(this === window);
}

foo(); // Logs "true"
```

**But**, in JavaScript, `this` is set entirely by how a function is called. So we could call `foo` setting `this` to something else:

```
var obj = {};
foo.call(obj); // Now it logs "false", `this` === `obj` during the call
```

Similarly:

```
var obj = {};
obj.f = foo;
obj.f(); // Also logs "false", `this` === `obj` during the call
```

So in conclusion, at global scope (not in any function call), yes, `this` is reliably pointing to the global object, and if you control how the function gets called and you call it without setting `this` to anything else (via `call` or `apply`, or by using it from an object property a'la `obj.f` above), then, again, it will reliably refer to the global object. This is covered by sections [10.4.1](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.1) *(Entering Global Code)* and [10.4.3](http://es5.github.com/#x10.4.3) *(Entering Function Code)* of the specification. This is how it's been from the very beginning, I believe; certainly for the last 15 years, so you're unlikely to find a non-compliant environment.

More reading:

- [Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)
- [You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Answer (score 2):

It will not work in modern browsers if someone slaps "use strict" above your code as `this` will be `undefined` inside the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
"use strict";


...


function test(){
console.log(this);
}

test(); // undefined
</script>
```

Note that you can save much more characters just by assigning `window` to some variable at the top of your code and using that as it will be shortened to some one character variable by a minimizer.

```
(function(global){
    global.foo();
    global.bar();
})(window);
```

would be minimized to (without whitespace):

```
(function(a){
    a.foo();
    a.bar();
})(window);
```

Where as `this` would not be touched as it's a keyword.

Comment: this and the ans of @Alex Wayne scared me enough to never use

Answer (score 1):

`this` *always* has a value.  And if `this` hasnt been overridden somehow, then it will be `window` where all your globals are.

It will work in all JS implementations, but beware! This is more brittle, and it won't always point to a global variable.

For instance:

```
var myVar = "global";
var obj = {
  myVar: "property",
  fn: function() { return this.myVar; }
}

console.log(obj.fn()); // "property"
```

This fails because in this context `this` is that object.  But when executing a function that is NOT a property of an object, `this` will default to window, like your example.